# Configuration for toolbar or any other section of Ckeditor 5 not reflecting in the UI

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am using the new ckeditor 5 component in my Angular 7 app. I have installed it successfully and able to bind the data to the ckeditor.
The problem I am facing is that i am not able set the configuration of the editor. No matter what I set in the configuration doesn't reflect in the editor. Could somebody point out what is wrong. If you see below i am trying to set the toolbar but that doesn't reflect on what is shown in the UI

UI

```
<div class="form-group row " >
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 30px;">
            <div class="desc-header">Notes </div>
            <div id = "divNotes" class="divEditor">
                <ckeditor  [editor]="Editor" [config]="getCKConfig" [id]="'ckNotes'" *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 11px;" debounce="500"
                 [(ngModel)]="ManagerDetails.Person.NOTES"> </ckeditor> 
                <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px" *ngIf="!EditMode" [innerHTML]="ManagerDetails.Person.NOTES">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component

```
getCKConfig() {
    return {

        contentsCss: ["body {font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;}"],
        pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles: false,
        height: '100px', width: '100%', readOnly: false, toolbar: [
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'], items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
            { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'], items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt'] },
            { name: 'source', items: ['Sourcedialog'] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'] }
        ]
    };
}
```

Comment: I even tried calling it like this but didnt make difference getCKConfig()

Answer (score 1):

There're two problems in your component:

First: `[config]` must be bound to the property, not the method. E.g. `<editor [config]="editorConfig">` and `@Component() class SomeClass{ editorConfig={} }` in the component

Second: `CKEditor 5` differs from `CKEditor 4`.  It has different architecture, different toolbar options, configuration, etc. See [CKEditor 5 configuration guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html) and [CKEditor 5 migration guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a variable and bind it directly

```
ckConfig =   {contentsCss: ["body {font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;}"],
        pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles: false,
        height: '100px', width: '100%', readOnly: false, toolbar: [
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'], items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
            { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'], items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt'] },
            { name: 'source', items: ['Sourcedialog'] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'] }
        ]};
```

Comment: I still dont find the configuration getting applied. has it changed in ckeditor 5 version. How do the same in ckeditor 5